# I need some suggestions to speed up my array manipulation code

Tags: javascript, performance

I have a function which from an array of days return the array of days with it's date like from array of

`['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed' ]` my function returns the days from today if there are some past days i switch the date to next week so the array will become  `['Wed 23', 'Sun 27', 'Mon 28', 'Tue 29' ]`

And here is how my function looks like (i've added all comments that specify what i'm doing on each step:

```
  moment.locale('it'); // setting locale to italian as API response returns it formatted days

    const days = ['lun', 'mar', 'mer', 'gio', 'ven', 'sab', 'dom']; // mapping weekdays which will be used to get index of the day to use in isoWeekday

    const momentToday = moment().isoWeekday(); // setting today date
    const arrayGiorni = giorni.map((g) => {
      const dayIndex = days.indexOf(g.giorno.toLowerCase()); // getting index of day from the object array es if g.giorno is 'mar' index will be 2
      if (momentToday <= dayIndex) { // checking if today is <= to mapping object then adding it to array
        return {
          id: g.id,
          giorno: moment().isoWeekday(dayIndex),
        };
      } else { // else skipping to next week and adding the object to array
        return {
          id: g.id,
          giorno: moment()
            .add(1, 'weeks')
            .isoWeekday(dayIndex),
        };
      }
    });

// sorting the array to get an ordered array of dates
    arrayGiorni.sort((a, b) => moment(a.giorno).valueOf() - moment(b.giorno).valueOf());

// formatting the moment object to get string formatted date
    this.giorni = arrayGiorni.map(g => g.giorno.format('ddd DD MMM'));

    console.log(this.giorni);
```

As asked in comments here is the model of giorni:

```
export class NegozioGiorni {
    constructor(
        public id: number,
        public giorno: string,
        public orari: string[] = []
    ) {}
}
```

That in array of objects will be `[ { id: 1, giorno: 'lun', orari: ['12:00', '13:00'] }, { id: 2, giorno: 'mer', orari: ['12:00', '13:00'] }, { id: 2, giorno: 'ven', orari: ['15:00', '17:00'] } ]`

I was wondering if there is something that i can reduce in this come and if there is a way to make it more performable.

Comment: What kind of performance gains are you looking for, speed, memory, ...?

Comment: @pacmaninbw i'm looking for speed improvment as the array will always contains max 7 elements the memory is not so important in that case

Comment: @CertainPerformance added the example of giorni and it's constructor if needed

Comment: PS moment is no longer in active development. You should find something else.

Comment: The current question title of your question is too generic to be helpful. Please edit to the site standard, which is for the title to simply **state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Speed** You say you want the program to run more quickly, but it looks pretty good to me already. Are you really processing such a huge number of `giorni` objects that the function doesn't run fast enough? (It's possible, but it sounds unlikely.) But there are some improvements that could be made.

**`indexOf` vs object** You use `indexOf` to find the position of the day in the days array. This has `O(n)` complexity; the interpreter searches through the array indicies one-by-one until it finds a match. It would be less computationally expensive to use an object mapping day names to their indicies, then look up the name on the object, in a single operation.

**Conditional values** Inside the `.map`, the only part that changes between the `if` and `else` is the `giorno` property. To do this more efficiently and concisely, use the conditional operator instead:

```
return {
  id: g.id,
  giorno: momentToday <= dayIndex
    ? moment().isoWeekday(dayIndex)
    : moment().add(1, 'weeks').isoWeekday(dayIndex),
};
```

. Or, since it you don't actually care about the `id` properties, you can remove them entirely, and just use an array of times.

**Moment** Moment is a non-trivial library (and even it recommends to use modern APIs instead, like `Date`). If speed is an issue, you could use the native `Date` object instead.

```js
const giorni = [{
  id: 1,
  giorno: 'lun', // Monday; turns into Mon 28 Sep
  orari: ['12:00', '13:00']
}, {
  id: 2,
  giorno: 'mer', // Wednesday: turns into Wed 23 Sep
  orari: ['12:00', '13:00']
}, {
  id: 2,
  giorno: 'ven', // Friday: turns into Fri 25 Sep
  orari: ['15:00', '17:00']
}];
const dayIndiciesByDayName = Object.fromEntries(
  ['dom', 'lun', 'mar', 'mer', 'gio', 'ven', 'sab']
    .map((name, i) => [name, i])
);

const todayDayIndex = new Date().getDay(); // Zero-indexed and starts at Sunday
const todayDayOfMonth = new Date().getDate();
const inputDays = giorni.map(({ giorno }) => giorno);
const itemDates = giorni.map((g) => {
  const itemDayIndex = dayIndiciesByDayName[g.giorno.toLowerCase()];
  // Below will be 0 to 6:
  const itemDayDifferenceFromToday = (itemDayIndex - todayDayIndex + 7) % 7;
  const itemDateObj = new Date();
  itemDateObj.setDate(todayDayOfMonth + itemDayDifferenceFromToday);
  return itemDateObj;
});
const output = itemDates
  .sort((a, b) => a - b)
  .map((date) => {
    const match = date.toString().match(/(\w+ )(\w+) (\d+ )/);
    return match[1] + match[3] + match[2];
  });
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Awesome explanation, i've swapped to `Date` API as you suggested as i've just read that Moment has some memory leaks in modern frameworks and as i'm using Angular the `Date` was what i needed